# Is there a good HLSL to SPIR-V compiler?

Tags: vulkan, hlsl, spir-v

I'm writing a voxel engine in C++, and I'm implementing a Vulkan renderer. I've decided to write shaders in HLSL, and translate them via SPIRV-Cross. However, this brings me to a problem - glslang's HLSL compiler does not allow samplers. For example, this pixel shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0 {
    return tex2D(tex, uv);
}
```

gives this compiler output:

```
Expected Sampled Image to be of type OpTypeSampledImage
  %19 = OpImageSampleImplicitLod %v4float %17 %18
```

I don't know if I should write my shaders in GLSL, or use a different library. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does HLSL use `sampler2D` as a type?

Comment: @NicolBolas As far as I know, yes.

Comment: @YodaSoda1219 Nicol is right, HLSL uses `SamplerState`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official DirectX Shader Compiler](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler) (that's the one for HLSL 6 and above, not the old DxCompiler) actually supports transforming HLSL into SPIR-V. See their [wiki page about it](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/wiki/SPIR%E2%80%90V-CodeGen) for an explanaition on how to build the compiler with that feature enabled, and how to use it.

That said, `uniform sampler2D tex;` is actually not HLSL but GLSL code. In HLSL, you would write

```
SamplerState sampler;
Texture2D tex;
float4 main(float2 uv : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0 {
    return tex.Sample(sampler, uv);
}
```